# nodejs module has warning message

Tags: node.js

Is there ant way I can silence a warning message caused by a module I include?

I like the module, but every time I call their function, the console outputs:

```
"Utf8String" type is deprecated, use "CString" instead
```

I am making a console app, so would prefer to surpress this message.

Comment: Ummm what "module" are you using?

Comment: Does it make a difference? I am using `execSync`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, there was a module required by a module I required, which had custom code which both used `Utf8String` and triggered an error for it.

```
// alias Utf8String
var utfstringwarned = false
Object.defineProperty(types, 'Utf8String', {
    enumerable: false
  , configurable: true
  , get: function () {
      if (!utfstringwarned) {
        utfstringwarned = true
        console.error('"Utf8String" type is deprecated, use "CString" instead')
      }
      return types.CString
    }
})
```

And wrote about it in the history

```
0.0.20 / 2012-06-27
===================

 - rename the `Utf8String` type to `CString` (#5)
 - make `Utf8String` an alias to `CString` and deprecated
 - more work on docs (not yet ready)
```

So as a temporary solution, I might comment out the error message, or as a more permanent solution, choose a different module.

Answer (score 0):

The warning messages you are getting are actually from node and not the module.
The module is however causing the warnings as its calling an api that was used in previous version of node.

I don't think there is anyway to tell node to surpress warning messages logged to the console.

If you really are determind to get rid of these warnings you can go into source code of the module and do a find and replace.

```
"Utf8String" to "CString"
```

I did the exact same thing for another module, I couldn't stand those messages either.

Comment: So... if I upgrade node (or anyone installing my package), then I could be breaking all my programs, by adding erroneous error messages unrelated to the program. That seems like a big problem to me. I am surprised there is no way to surpress node warnings. Are you sure?

Comment: Yes, when-ever node is upgraded some of its api's are removed or renamed. To encourage module authors to switch to new api's node tries to be helpful and logs a warning message to the console. I am pretty sure there is no way to surpress these messages but am not 100%.

Comment: Turns out this warning was from the module, which is probably why it is so non-specific!